# Doubt regarding research paper on Crowd Counting using Convolutional neural networks and Markov Random Field

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks

I am currently reading the research paper [Image Crowd Counting Using Convolutional Neural Network and Markov Random Field](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03686.pdf)  by Kang Han, Wanggen Wan, Haiyan Yao, and Li Hou. 
I did not understand the following context properly:

> Formally, the
>   Markov random field framework for the crowd counting
>   can be defined as follows (we follow the notation in [18]).
>   Let P be the set of patches in an image and C be a possi-
>   ble set of counts. A counting c assigns a count c p ∈ C to
>   each patch p ∈ P. The quality of a counting is given by an
>   energy function:
>
> E(c) =
>   ∑ D p (c p ) + ∑
>   p∈P
>   V (c p − c q )
>   . . . (2)
>   (p,q)∈N
>
> where N are the (undirected) edges in the four-connected
>   image patch graph. D p (c p ) is the cost of assigning count
>   c p to patch p, and is referred to as the data cost. V (c p −c q )
>   measures the cost of assigning count c p and c q to two
>   neighboring patch, and is normally referred to as the dis-
>   continuity cost.
>   For the problem of smoothing the adjacent patches
>   count, D p (c p ) and V (c p − c q ) can take the form of the
>   following functions:
>   D p (c p ) = λ min((I(p) − c p ) 2 , DATA K) . . . (3)
>   V (c p − c q ) = min((c p − c q ) 2 , DISC K)
>   . . . (4)
>   where λ is a weight of the energy items, I(p) is the ground
>   truth count of the patch p, DATA K and DISC K are the
>   truncating item of D p (c p ) and V (c p − c q ), respectively.

---

Can anyone explain the above part in detail and give me a detailed insight on how should I implement this part of the project?

Comment: Is there any way in which you could come up with a more descriptive title? Particularly for others who face the same issue as you do. Right now the title is so generic and non-descriptive, that any great answers you may receive will not be found by others in a search.

Comment: @Bart I have edited the title.